# SSH unzip BUT with CASE-SENSITIVITY

Tags: ssh, case-sensitive, unzip

I have am trying to unzip a file via SSH, I require a case sensitive unzip.

My server is using Debian Unzip 6.

It shouldn't be doing this, but it is converting all my file names to lower case, causing my Joomla site to buckle.

There are far too many files to rename manually or to FTP if I want to finish in my lifetime.

I have a zip called bv2.zip placed in the directory I want to extract in...

I have cd'd into my directory and simply issued: unzip bv2.zip .... filenames all go to lowercase...

I have also tried absolute paths to no avail, the UNZIP help and manual states that case sensitivity is enabled by default with this version, but obviously not...

Any ideas??

Comment: What error do you get with "unzip bv2.zip"?

Comment: sorry, not an error, just the case insensitive behaviour that i've mentioned when i try to unzip

Comment: What is your originating filesystem?  If OSX that may be the problem as OSX's file system is case insensitive.

Comment: debian - unix web server (most certainly case sensitive os)

Comment: I agree with @thenetimp, the problems seems to be related to the original OS, the zip file itself must contain only lowercase filenames.

Comment: ahhhh, sorry ORIGINATING fs.... That would be Win7, so NTFS

Comment: @flexag you said the server was debian, but what is the machine you are creating the file from?  OS X and Windows are a both case insensitive file systems, but  think that OS X may be more forgiving.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what does unzip -v file.zip show? The docs say

> by  default  unzip lists and
>                 extracts such filenames exactly  as  they're  stored  (excepting
>                 truncation,  conversion  of  unsupported characters, etc.)

It'd be worth checking how they are stored. If the creating zip program is storing them all as lowercase, then that's where you need to look for a way to actually store unaltered filenames.

Finally, just to be sure, check that there's no alias or environment variable on your Debian server forcing use of the -L option. Look at output of the following commands, run on the Debian server's terminal:

```
alias
```

(there should be no weird alias for unzip)

```
echo $UNZIP
```

(Any flags contained in this environment variable will be used by unzip as if they'd been added to the command invocation).

Comment: You got it my man.... the web hosting company, in there ever infinite wisdom had set an alias: alias unzip='unzip -L'

Comment: For anyone who's been looking for a solution I over-road my hosting company's alias by using `\unzip example.zip`

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem in my 1&1 hosting. I have solved it by defining a new alias, by typing:

```
alias unzip='unzip'
```

The problem was unzip -L was aliased.

Now I have unzipped prestashop backup and it works like a charm

Regards

Comment: Thank you!! This was driving me nuts!

Comment: Im happy to be useful

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your .zip file didn't have all lowercase names to begin with? Maybe whatever program you used to create the zip file is converting the names to lowercase.

Comment: Just Win7's built in zip function, the original files def have Uppercase portions of names and so do the files inside the zip

Comment: Oh I would never trust Windows to do the right thing. If all else fails, I'd try another zip utility. Can't recommend one as I'm not too familiar with Windows; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. The "-L" (convert all filenames to lowercase) and "U" (convert all filenames to upper case) options control this behavior:

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/unzip.1.asp

1. This would ONLY be an issue if the files in the .zip were from a case-insensitive filesystem (like MS-DOS or VAX/VMS).  It should *not* be an issue if the files were .zipped up on ANY contemporary filesystem (Unix, MacOS, Windows 95 or higher) with ANY contemporary version of Zip or WinZip.

Soooo ......

1. Is there any chance these are DOS files?

   Or did you use a DOS version of PKZip?

   Or were the files simply lower case to begin with?

Comment: Careful. He's using unzip 6.0, for which -U has a different behavior. The man page you quote even says "(obsolete; to be removed in a future release)"